# Delimiter em procedure mysql

Tags: mysql

Estou a executar uma `procedure`, porém minha aplicação web formata essa procedure e a executa no `mysql`. O problema é que, quando a procedure é executada, ela fica em apenas uma linha (sem quebra de linhas). Por exemplo:

```
DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE executar_procedure ()  BEGIN /*Meu código aqui!*/ END//  DELIMITER ;
```

Então, como ao executar no `mysql` tudo fica em apenas uma linha, o DELIMITER reconhece todo o código depois de `//` como se ainda fizesse parte do delimiter, ou seja, o delimiter não pega apenas as duas barras para indicar que alí esta comecando a procedure, mas sim, todo o conteúdo que está na linha, e assim, não consigo executar a procedure.
Ja tentei usar \n depois de "DELIMITER //" mas não obtive sucesso.

Obrigado a todos que tentarem ajudar!

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. Não desfaça a formatação em linha de código, ela existe justamente para destacar o código do restante da pergunta e para tornar sua formação mais facil de ler.